# How to set ResponseCode = 200 ok with elapsed time 0 as Fail in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I want to over-ride the status in j-meter for 200-OK with elapsed time 0ms.

Actually i have used java with jmeter, and put SampleResult.sampleStart() and sampleEnd() for measuring time taken by the sampler, but in some case due to some exception and error my that block of code is not being executed so my elapsed time is coming zero(0) but with status "200 ok" as pass .

I want to fail that scenario.

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance.

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
for (int count = 0; count <= 100; count++) {
    if (WDS.browser.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='divshow loadingimage']//span[@class='spinnerloader loadermain']")).size() > 0) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WDS.log.info("Waiting for spinners to disappear");
    } else {
        WDS.log.info("Break----------");
        break;
    }
}
WDS.log.info("Page Loaded");
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

Comment: if you could  provide the code we can help you debug it.

Comment: @Mustahsan i am very new to jmeter, just want to know that is there is any way we can set 200 ok status to fail?

Comment: its ok to be new. just share your code here in which you have written your logic which has problem.

Comment: @Mustahsan in the above code due to some error the code inside WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart did not get executed and due to that my elapsed time get "0" as a value but its status did not say false or fail or warning but it says pass. So i want to know if there is any way that i can change that 200 ok "pass" status to fail??

Comment: please edit your question and add it there. its to hard to read it here.

Comment: @Mustahsan edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if("200".equals(SampleResult.getResponseCode())&&
    "0".equals(SampleResult.time.toString())) 

       { // Success

SampleResult.setSuccessful(false); // Change sampler status to success
AssertionResult.setFailure(true); // Set assertion status to success as well
   } 
    else {
   AssertionResult.setFailure(false); // Set assertion status to failure
   }
```

posted this code in JSR223 assertion. i get the desired result and the assertion should be inside the sampler i.e at the sampler level..